# how i can download file more than 20 mb from bot using python?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Ok, I know in telegram bot API we can get the file_id and send it to getFile method and it will give us the file path so we can download it with an URL.

BUT it has a maximum limit of the file size of 20MB for each file.

Here is my question:

How can this [bot](https://t.me/GetPublicLinkBot) bypass the size limitation?

Personally wouldn't believe that until tested it with a 200MB sized file and it worked very fast. I want to make one like that.

how possible i can do same i use telethon and i get api_id and api_hash any advice please it will be apricated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this via public Bot API in due to their limitations: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile, https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files

But you can do this via local Bot API Server: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server
Or just use Client API directly for working with files. local Bot API Server has the same limitations as Client API.

Local server:
Can be compiled from [official repository](https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api) or used via third-party Docker images https://hub.docker.com/r/aiogram/telegram-bot-api
And --local mode is required (TELEGRAM_LOCAL=1 env. var if you use my Docker image)

Client API:
aiogram can be used at the same time with one of Client API library like [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/), [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) or [tdlib](https://github.com/tdlib/td) for working with files.

Comment: thank you , and yes your replay solve my issue , thank you

Answer (score 0):

These file size limits are set for the [Telegram Bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) API. So I wouldn't recommend using the pyTelegramBotAPI module for your purpose. Rather use the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api/bots), which uses the MTProto protocol rather than Bot API endpoints. This allows for maximum file sizes of [2GB](https://telegram.org/blog/profile-videos-people-nearby-and-more?ln=r).

Modules such as [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) or pyrogram allow to create bots that use [MTProto](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/mtproto-vs-botapi).

Comment: Thank u for your answer , my issue not to send file as is ok and it is 2GB , my issue is to downloads videos on my server using pyhton as it limit to 20MB